# form input type text jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not know why I cannot get access to the input text when the code does not have any error.

```
<form action="#">
                <table width="80%" align="center">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Write your name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Name" /></td>

                        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
            <p />
            <div id="nameResult"></div>
```

and the js (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sendName').click(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var tag = $('#yourName').val();

                $('<p>Name ' + tag + '</p>').appendTo('#nameResult');

            });
    }); 

})
```

The output is always undefined. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You realize the input has no ID, it has a name ?

Comment: you had not defined id for you input but trying to access the value using id i.e. #yourName in JS script

Comment: Why on earth are you calling `$(document).ready` inside the click event?

Comment: Put the listener on the form's submit handler as the form can be submitted without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `name`as if it is an `id` using `#`.

Change this

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Name" />
```

to this, in which the input control has an `id` defined:

```
<input type="text" id="yourName" name="yourName" placeholder="Name" />
```

If you prefer to `stick` to name and do not want to define an `id`, then you can do this as well:

```
var tag = $('input[name="yourName"]').val();
```

Comment: @user6527926 please see the update, you can also just use this `var tag = $('input[name="yourName"]').val();` in your jquery

Comment: I will no worries, I have to wait 10 mins to do it... :) Thanks again